# How to get out of command block loop in education edition

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I gave myself a command block and made it so that it would teleport me to my house. I forgot I was using a repeating command block, and there is no setting to turn off command blocks in the education edition. How do I stop it from teleporting me?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. Go into settings and scroll down and it is at the bottom.[image: Picture of the Game Settings]

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing in a server and have access to the server console, you can use the following command:

> /gamerule commandBlocksEnabled false

To enable command blocks again, use

> /gamerule commandBlocksEnabled true

If you are playing on single player, check the answer by AwesomeT43.